# Use a wooden frame to avoid dissipation of high-frequency current?

Tags: power-electronics, high-frequency, induction

In reading a description of a 32-kilowatt induction heater of the spark gap type by Frank Curtis (p. 29), I see the following passage describing the enclosure:

> The entire assembly is mounted within a wooden frame so that stray
>   high-frequency currents will not be absorbed or otherwise dissipated.

To what effect is he referring? He seems to be suggesting that if the machine had a metal enclosure, it could somehow leach power out of the circuit and therefore it is better to make the frame out of wood.

The book in question is "High-Frequency Induction Heating" (1944).

Comment: Yes. Most of the field is inside the coil but some fringes escape, especially at the ends. "Wooden" should be read as "cheap insulating material readily available in 1944" though it has its own disadvantages around high temperatures and can be transformed into conductive carbon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of the induction heater coil as the primary of a transformer and the item being heated as the [secondary](http://www.acrossinternational.com/25KW-Mid-Frequency-Compact-Induction-Heater-w-Timers-30-80KHz-IH25A.htm):

[image: http://www.acrossinternational.com/25KW-Mid-Frequency-Compact-Induction-Heater-w-Timers-30-80KHz-IH25A.htm]

Note that field lines extend out beyond the coil- if there is metal outside that forms a conductive path, then voltage can be induced in the metal causing current to flow, which will waste energy heating the outside metal. You can think of it like a shorted turn on a transformer. Wood is slightly conductive so some current would flow, but the heating effect (and the opposing magnetic field) would be negligible.

The effect of a highly conductive shorted turn loosely coupled, like a barely conductive turn, is not highly lossy- it results in a lowering of inductance of the coil.

There will be an impedance at which energy transfer is maximized- preferably most of that energy is transferred to the sample being heated and not to other items.

Answer (score 1):

> He seems to be suggesting that if the machine had a metal enclosure, it could somehow leach power out of the circuit ...

Of course! That's the whole idea of how induction heating works: A strong magnetic field is used to induce a current in a conductive material, and that current is converted to heat by the resistance of the material.

The magnetic field can't discriminate between "target" and "enclosure" — ANY metal (or other conductor) that it encounters will be heated. And if any part of the enclosure forms a complete path (a.k.a. "shorted turn") around the coil, it will absorb MOST of the power being applied and heat up very rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what he's referring to.

Any closed loop of conductor that's close to the heating coil, and in this context close means within about one coil radius in any direction, will have quite significant voltages generated it in.

If the conductor is copper or alli, so not too lossy, then the effect will be to tune the coil up slightly. If it's steel, so very lossy, it will absorb significant power from the work coil. If the loop has loose connections, say rusty joints between bits of a frame, those high resistance areas could get hot or spark.